# dynamic javascript/jquery form submission with results from php/mysql

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

I would like to create a search page which allows somebody to select a number of options (check boxes) which in turn creates multiple WHERE clauses in a SQL statement but not sure how to go about this.

In simple terms - if I check the boxes for: "pending", "submited", "processed" then hit submit on my form, a sql statement is created which basically says:

"SELECT * FROM table.tablename WHERE (pending="Y", submitted="Y", processed="Y")... and so on.

The items in the parenthesis will be dynamic so the sql statement will not always be the same and the values do not necessarily equal Y (i would like to use prepared statements in PDO for this).

any ideas?

## EDIT

based on responses it seems some are assuming the fieldnames in the WHERE clause are known. As I mention in another comment below, there could be 2 or 2000 fieldnames in this clause, none of which are known to the system ahead of time (if checkbox A is checked, include it, if not, dont...)

SELECT * FROM table WHERE ($whereclause_string)

where

$whereclausestring = "unknown_field1=unknownvalue1, unknown_field2=unknownvalue2, unknown_field3=unknownvalue3..."

Comment: @ken - let's assume the only 'script' i have tried to run with is the example above in the edit - that is in essence my entire question so posting out a full script makes no sense when modifying the sql statement alone is what I am trying to accomplish. I do not want to run multiple statements so running anything in a loop is not worth it either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps something like this?

```
<?php
// construction
$options = array('foo', 'bar');
foreach ($options as $option)
    printf('%s: <input type="checkbox" value="%s" />%s', $option, $option, PHP_EOL);

// submission
$wheres = array();
foreach ($options as $option)
    if (isset($_POST[$option])) // should only be present if "checked"
        $wheres[] = sprintf('%s = "%s"', $option, mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[$option])); // sanitize!!

$where = implode(', ', $wheres); // foo = "yes", bar = "yes"
?>
```

**EDIT:** The jQuery should be easy for this, using a selector such as `'input:checked'` to gather all of the checked options.

Comment: i like it - i think ill take it from here. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming this is a web page (as you are talking about checkboxes, search &c., and that it is tagged with javascript and PHP.)

These checkboxes must, then, be part of a form. I would think you need to harvest the submitted data (which would be as name=value pairs), and insert the variables as you construct the query.

How you do this would depend on the context of the SQL query, but, I think the simplest way, if not the most secure, would be to construct the query as follows (in your PHP script):

```
"SELECT * FROM table.tablename WHERE ('pending = ' . $_POST['pending'] . ', submitted = ' . $_POST['submitted'] . ', processed = ' . $_POST['processed']);"
```

'POST' can be substitued with 'GET', if necessary, or even 'COOKIE' or 'REQUEST', although, you probably want to be more sure what you are getting.

Also in terms of security, it would be extremely wise to check that the values are what you expect them to be, in order to prevent SQL injection. You can do this by checking the values against certain conditions (using conditional loops), and assigning them to a local variable if the checks prove successful.

Hope this helps you.

Chops

Comment: your code assumes I am using the pending, submitted, etc variables each time. I am not necessarily selecting or using all variables within my table, hence the purpose of my question. I want to dynamically create the SELECT/INSERT/UPDATE statement based on the parameters selected in the form.

Comment: Sorry. I, like others, had misunderstood this. I think it might be helpful to think where the unknown_fields would come from- presumably they relate to the table, and I guess the column headers. The $options array in Ken's answer could then be generated dynamically by fetching the column headers and inserting them into the array.

Answer (score 0):

Create PHP script with MySQL connection and query. Then use jQuery to make AJAX or JSON request to PHP script.

PHP:

```
header('content-type:application/json;charset=utf-8');
$defaults = array('pending' => 'Y','submitted' => 'Y','processed' => 'Y');
$pending = ($_GET['pending']) ? $_GET['pending'] : $defaults['pending'];
$submitted = ($_GET['submitted']) ? $_GET['submitted'] : $defaults['submitted'];
$processed = ($_GET['processed']) ? $_GET['processed'] : $defaults['processed'];

$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');
$db = mysql_select_db('foo', $link);
$query = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM table.tablename WHERE (pending="'.$penging.'", submitted="'.$submitted.'", processed="'.$processed.'")');
$result = array();

if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: '.mysql_error());
}

if (!$db_selected) {
    die ('Can\'t use foo : '.mysql_error());
}

if (!$result) {
    die('Invalid query: '.mysql_error());
}

$i = 0;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $result[$i]['row-name'] = $row['row-name'];
    $i++;
}

mysql_close($link);

return json_encode($result);
```

jQuery:

```
$('#some-submit-button').click(function(){
    var pending = $('#some-pending-input').val(),
    submitted = $('#some-submitted-input').val(),
    processed = $('#some-processed-input').val();

    $.getJSON('/path/to/script.php?pending=' + pending + '&submitted=' + submitted + '&processed=' + processed,function(data){
        $.each(data,function(i){
            $('#some-block-for-results').append('Getting data from MySQL never been so easy: ' + data[i].some-row-name + ', ' + data[i].some-other-row-name);
        });
    });
    return false;
});
```

This is just a quick example. Change PHP/jQ for your needs.

Comment: perhaps the phrasing of my question was confusing but i was only using Y values for the variables above as an example - the variables in the where statement could chagne (could be 2 could be 200). I want to be able to pass entire variables, not just values for the unknown fieldnames

Comment: So, what's the problem? I wrote a simple AJAJ model for MySQL. Sceleton. Just modify the query, conditions (if/else statements) and passing variables.

Comment: i appreciate the help but you basically posted a loop for the same 'idea' code I have above. i will not know the default fields, values or anything for the $default. The sql command above also assumes you search based of 3 *known* fieldnames- which I wont. In my example, I assume the customer may search by every fieldname in the system or one - that choice is up to them but your sample code assumes you know what they will enter and/or what "default" values will be

Comment: Those default values just for security reasons when you have only two variants of your value (like Y or N). If you want to make a value independent query, you need to change 'if' statements. For example:
$submitted = ($_GET['submitted']) ? 'WHERE submitted = "'.$_GET['submitted']"' : '';
...
mysql_query('SELECT * FROM table WHERE '.$submitted);

You know, it's just 'for fun'. In real life you need more conditions and more security tricks.